# l1 shared bank conflict profiler counter for CUDA CC 3.0

Tags: cuda, gpu, profiler, gpu-shared-memory

What is the new `l1_shared_bank_conflict` (or the equivalent) counter for CUDA with CC 3.0?
In CUPTI User Guide, it says `shared_[load|store]_bank_conflict`, but it didn't show when I tried so.

I'm using the command line profiler in Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the new counters are not supported by the old command line profiler. If you are using CUDA 5, you can try nvprof:

```
nvprof --events l1_shared_bank_conflict <app_name>

nvprof --query-events
```

See http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview

Comment: Thanks @Joe. It's actually shared_[load|store]_replay. --query-events option is really helpful!